# Have my bot join the person who sent the command instead of having it be in a pre set VC

Tags: python, discord.py

my code currently is this

```
voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name='Music')
await voiceChannel.connect()
```

how do i change this so it joins the author instead of joining a VC Labelled "Music"

Answer (score 0):

If you need anymore help after this, consider joining [this small discord server](https://discord.gg/XVKdgE5472).

Here's the code I use for mine:

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    channel = author.voice_channel
    await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
```